# null exception in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I met with the following error from the following javascript functions, any ideas what is wrong?

BTW: since the whole page is long, I can not post them all here. I am trying to find a small but complete sample to reproduce this issue. Any ideas to debug further to find the root cause?

```
'Null' is null or not an object
```

Script:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#tag0").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
      });
</script>
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Does the code work without problems when you remove this piece?

Comment: For tooltip function, I am using this library. http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Comment: Use firebug in firefox or developer tools in chrome, and you should be able to click on that error and it'll take you directly to the line that caused it. Then - post that line and its surrounding code here.

Comment: Do you have any stray trailing commas anywhere? E.g. `var a = [ 1, 2, ];`. IE puts an implicit `null` at the end of such things and then someone iterates over the array and finds a surprise `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess was that

```
$("#tag0")
```

is returning null, and attempting to call a method on null is probably giving you the error. I have been informed that jQuery won't actually return null if your selector doesn't match anything -- you just get an empty set of results with a length property of 0. If you call a nonexistent method on an object of this result type, perhaps you get the error message you're seeing.

Is it possible there isn't actually an element on the page with ID "tag0"? Should it be a class instead (".tag0" instead of "#tag0")?

Comment: jQuery's `$(x)` won't return null, it returns something such that `$(x).length == 0` is true instead.

Comment: @mu Thanks, I've updated the comment to reflect the jQuery behavior here.

Comment: I find tag0 is defined in this way, <a id="tag0">order0</a>, is that correct?

Comment: How to check whether tag0 is defined or not? Is there is quick way to test?

Comment: What's the result of document.getElementById("tag0")? If it's defined and non-null, then the element exists with that ID.